# Heatmap weighted only by value, not concentration

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Im trying to make make a heatmap using `WeightedLatLng`. Right now it shows an increase in "intensity" for high values or for multiple lower values close together.
I want to be able to only take in to account the values of the weights, not the sum of different points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyway you can create custom [Ground Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/groundoverlay) or [Tile Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/tileoverlay) with your own algorithm for heatmap. As start point for heatmap creation you can use for example [AndroidHeatMap](https://github.com/HeartlandSoftware/AndroidHeatMap) project of [tredpath](https://github.com/tredpath).